# How to execute a command after a certain period of inactivity, triggered by keyboard & mouse activity and full screen window?

Tags: xorg, scripts, time, fullscreen, execute-command

My machine suspends after 5 minutes of inactivity, however I want to execute a command as well after 4 minutes and 30 seconds of inactivity. Is there a way to run a command after 4 minutes and 30 seconds of *no* full screen window and no keyboard- and mouse activity?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18. I have already looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202136/how-can-a-script-detect-a-users-idle-time). However, `xprintidle` is not triggered by a full screen window, only by keyboard- and mouse activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a script detect a user's idle time?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202136/how-can-a-script-detect-a-users-idle-time)

Comment: A 100% match (keyboard/mouse).That's where I got it in the first place.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Ah, sorry, I missed something out of my question that I'm not sure that covers...

Comment: It does, `xprintidle` is *only* triggered by keyboard- and mouse activity, Not what happens on the screen.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your latest edit. It fulfils  *exactly* what you ask for...

Comment: Ah, wait, you want the script to "pass" if any of your windows is maximized? What about the suspend then? Also: what is the context?

Comment: So if an application is fullscreen *don't* trigger the script? Just to remove my close vote.

Comment: @kos: Yes, spot on! If an application is fullscreen, don't trigger the the script! Because this needs to be executed 30 seconds before a suspend, and a suspend won't take place if an application is not fullscreen.

Comment: single screen or do you have multiple?

Comment: Also should idle time *start* only if no fullscreen window, or *hold* as long as a window is fullscreen. Also, finally fullscreen or maximized?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Since screen, and if there is an application which is fullscreen then it should not start counting. **Fullscreen**, not maximized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Running a command after idle time, triggered by both full screen *and* mouse/keyboard activity

Hi Paranoid Panda, the script below should do as you describe.

The issue was that both having a (any) window full screen, as well as mouse- or keyboard activities should reset the "real" idle time. Since `xprintidle` cannot be reset from command line, I solved it by subtracting the idle time from itself on the occasion of a full screen window:

- In a loop, the scripts looks up the current idle time
- if any window is maximized (checking if any window is as large as the screen's resolution, using both `xrandr` and `wmctrl -lG`), the *current* idle time is subtracted from the idle time, resulting in a correct "real" idle time, even when the window is not full screen any more.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys

idletime = int(sys.argv[1])
command = sys.argv[2]

get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

def get_res():
    xr = [s for s in get(["xrandr"]).split() \
          if "+0+0" in s][0].split("x"); xr[1] = xr[1].split("+")[0]
    return xr

res = get_res()

def check():
    front = [l for l in get(["xprop", "-root"]).splitlines() \
             if "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW):" in l][0].split("#")[-1].strip()
    front = front[:2]+(10-len(front))*"0"+front[2:]
    try:
        wdata = subprocess.check_output(
            ["wmctrl", "-lG"]
            ).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
        match = [l for l in wdata if front in l][0].split()[4:6]
        if match == res:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

minus = 0; real_idle = 0; t1 = 0; due_1 = False
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    fscreen = check()
    t2 = int(int(get(["xprintidle"]))/1000)
    if t2 < t1:
        minus = 0; real_idle = 0
    else:
        if fscreen == True:
            minus = t2
    real_idle = t2 - minus
    due_2 = [real_idle > idletime][0]
    if all([real_idle > idletime, due_1 != due_2]):
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
    due_1 = due_2
    t1 = t2
```

#### To use

- the script needs `wmctrl` and `xprintidle`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xdotool xprintidle
  ```
- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `run_ontime.py`
- Run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/run_ontime.py <seconds> <command>
  ```

  where the command needs to be between quotes if it contains spaces. I tested it for example with:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/run_ontime.py 10 "firefox askubuntu.com"
  ```

  which did the job :)

#### Note

The command is executed once every time the time passes idle time.